# Node.js Server with PM2 Crashing with error ENOMEM - but no memory leak

Tags: amazon-ec2, memory, node.js, memory-usage

I  have an EC2 instance running a node.js server (Express based).

After deploying in a new environment, my service had started crashing almost instantly with `spawn ENOMEM` Errors like this one:

[image: spawn ENOMEM]

Server logs do not indicate unusual activity. Diff from other environment is only config string such as DB hostname.

I have started all possible monitoring on server but nothing shows. No higher memory of the process or the machine, and no peaks in CPU/RAM Usage.

[image]

To be certain this is not a memory issue I have tried enlarging the instance from t2.micro to t2.large (2GB->8GB RAM), despite running the same process on a micro in a different environment. Still, the process crashes in a manner of minutes.

I strongly believe this is *NOT* a memory leak, but might be some sort of a memory allocation problem.
Has anyone encountered a problem as such?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.